# Can't apply template to OneNote in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, onenote

I have opened the SharePoint online OneNote in my Desktop OneNote and created a template. Then I applied the template to a section.

Now every page that is created in that section uses the template. However, the OneNote online does not apply the template on newly created pages.

Does anyone know why this is not working on OneNote online?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this feature is currently not implemented in OneNote online.

**Template support**

Not available in OneNote Online. With the OneNote desktop app, you can use a template as a page design that can be applied to new pages in your notebook to give them an appealing background, a more uniform appearance, or a consistent layout.

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/onenote-online-service-description.aspx)

You can use OneNote Online to open, display, and edit existing pages created from a template. However, creating and customizing new page templates isn't possible with OneNote Online.

OneNote Online is great if you're looking to change text styles, apply text formatting, and use note tags to begin a custom page layout. You can then finish creating and saving it as a custom template in the OneNote desktop app. For detailed steps about how to do this in OneNote 2016, see Create or customize a page template.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-customize-a-page-template-in-OneNote-Online-3a7600e8-de97-4f76-818f-1cacecf8596b)